# R: Using system command to move all files in a folder except one in MacOS

Tags: r, command-line-interface, system

I am trying to move files using R through the system command.  But I am unable to do so. Any insights on why would help. I know it is a convoluted way of doing it...  But i was curious and decided to try this through R. (It works through the command line directly.)

I tried both the system and system2 command. The command will execute the following: Move all files in the directory except `zplots` into the `./Resfiles` directory.

```
system('shopt -s extglob')
system('mv !(zplots) ./Resfiles')
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `mv !(zplots) ./Resfiles'

system2('mv !(zplots) ./Resfiles')
sh: mv -r !(zplots) ./Resfiles: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't get the difference between your two examples.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the code.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the code sections, does it really reflect what you get as output ? (if not, copy paste the output, then select it and press the code formatting button or ctrl+k)

Comment: And I really don't understand why you're using `paste0` here.

Comment: Hi i have edited the code and this is the final trial i had tried. I was in the correct directory. I was also able to just use ```mv``` without the ```!(filename)``` to move any files in the directory. The problem happens only when i have the '!' to indicate that it is an exception that should not be moved. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: Sorry I'm far unsure this could work without a heavy trick like calling bash specifically. your first one on one call may work (or not depending on how the shell behave on macOSX), I.e: `system('shopt -s extglob; mv !(zplots) ./Resfiles')`. I would recommend against this kind of use as it's really not portable.